# undefined method `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007fe67aa20ea0

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, flutter, cocoapods

Updated ruby to the version 3.0.2 and now getting these issues on a Flutter project.

OS: macOS Monterey 12.0 beta.

Running command: pod install

```
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.5.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.0.0)
Installing nanopb (2.30908.0)
Generating Pods project
[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

undefined method `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007f90151d0f18 @defined_in_file=#<Pathname:/Users/organic/CloudMail/IT/Development/Flutter/bloc_network_example/ios/Podfile>, @internal_hash={}, @root_target_definitions=[#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition label=Pods>], @current_target_definition=#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition label=Pods>, @post_install_callback=#<Proc:0x00007f9014464460 /Users/organic/CloudMail/IT/Development/Flutter/bloc_network_example/ios/Podfile:16>, @installation_options=#<Pod::Installer::InstallationOptions:0x00007f90159b42c0 @clean=true, @deduplicate_targets=true, @deterministic_uuids=true, @integrate_targets=true, @lock_pod_sources=true, @warn_for_multiple_pod_sources=true, @warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo=true, @share_schemes_for_development_pods=false, @disable_input_output_paths=false, @preserve_pod_file_structure=false, @generate_multiple_pod_projects=false, @incremental_installation=false, @skip_pods_project_generation=false>>

/Users/organic/CloudMail/IT/Development/Flutter/bloc_network_example/ios/Podfile:18:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
/Users/organic/CloudMail/IT/Development/Flutter/bloc_network_example/ios/Podfile:17:in `each'
/Users/organic/CloudMail/IT/Development/Flutter/bloc_network_example/ios/Podfile:17:in `block (2 levels) in from_ruby'
/Users/organic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:179:in `post_install!'
/Users/organic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:897:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/Users/organic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:885:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
...
/Users/organic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /Users/organic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    /Users/organic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

Running command `flutter doctor -v` drops this error `CocoaPods installed but not working. You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.`

```
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.0, Build version 13A5155e
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to
        invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
      To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Did you suddenly switch to using RVM? If not, why does your question title involve the System ruby? It looks to me like the error message is right: the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used. You need to start all over with all gems including cocoapods being in the new RVM ruby.

Comment: Hey Mat, thanks for your notice, mate. Sorry, it's my bad. I indeed decided to install a new version of the Ruby v.3.0.2, but haven't continued as UPD with further errors. Unfortunatelly, the new RVM ruby doesn't help to solve this problem.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? @organicnz

Comment: Could you pls try out my tutorial on FlutterFlow? Hopefully it helps, mate :)
https://community.flutterflow.io/c/community-tutorials/solved-error-running-pod-install-error-launching-application-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Error running pod install; Error launching application on iPhone.

https://community.flutterflow.io/c/community-tutorials/solved-error-running-pod-install-error-launching-application-on-iphone

Hopefully it solves your problem when it happens

Thank you :)